# How to use SharedPreference to save score and name in a game?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating my first android app and I don’t have enough knowledge in programming unlike other here. So please help me with this matter. I want to save player’s name and score. I’ve searched and read a lot about SharedPreference but was unable to understand it very well especially when I am already applying the codes on my activity. I have tried it twice and everytime I run it, it shows”Not Responding” message and closes. But when the codes for sharedpreference are not indicated there it works fine. So here’s how I want to do with these. On the first game, the very first score should be saved after the time is over (the user will be typing their name and click save). So when another user or player plays the game the Top Score should be indicated in the screen using a textview, below this Top Score textview is the Current Score textview. If the Current Score is greater than the Top Score then it should overwrite the score. If not then the Top Score should stay the same. How can I achieve this?

P.S. I have 3 different activities that needs this SharedPreferences but with the same functionalities. Thanks in advance. And please explain it more clearly (coz sometimes I can’t understand some words) thank you :)

**This is the code i use, i put it in Oncreate**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putInt("score", score);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see where the error is :)

Comment: I updated my Q above :)

Answer (score 3):

I think following link will surely help you out [SharedPreferences Explained in detail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value); //similar way you can push integer values
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        sp.getString(key, null); //default value will be null in this case, if there is no such key
```

You can write a Utility class to reuse this methods wher you want. like below

```
public class PreferenceUtility {

    public static void saveString(Activity activity, String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String readString(Activity activity, String key, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        return sp.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi :) Can you explain how this works? I also updated my Q above :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 static SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
    public static String Preference_Name = "AppData";



    public static String getPreference(String key, String Default,
            Activity activity)
    {
        sh_Pref = activity.getSharedPreferences(Preference_Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sh_Pref.getString(key, Default);
    }

    public static void setPreference(String key, String value, Activity activity)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {

                sh_Pref = activity.getSharedPreferences(Preference_Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = sh_Pref.edit();
                editor.putString(key, value);
                editor.commit();


        }

    }
}
```

** Here a set and get value from SharedPreferences**

Comment: Hi :) Can you explain how this works? I also updated my Q above :)